# pointers behaving differently on each compilation?

Tags: c++

What are the ambiguities in C++ that lead pointers to behave differently on each compilation?
If we comment then remove the comment, incrementing a pointer by 1 for example leads to different result each time we run the program.

The program behaves differently on visual studio only; on xcode however, the results are consistent.

```
#include <Windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {

    int a = 5; 
    printf("adress of a = %d\n\n", &a);
    int *p; p= &a; 
    printf("The address of a in p = %d\n", &a);

    *p = *p +1;

    (*p++); 
    printf("p after (*p++); = %d\n", p); 
    printf("a = %d\n\n", a);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: It just means you have a bug in your program.

Comment: I experienced this kind of behavior when a variable, maybe also a pointer, is not initialized. Since your pointer is not initialized correctly, it points to the value that is in memory when you run your program.

Comment: Smells like undefined behaviour. Can you give us some code?

Comment: @Otomo here is the code

Comment: @juanchopanza here is the code

Comment: Definite undefined behaviour (you should be ashamed)

Comment: @DieterLücking here is the code

Comment: @Predator44 which makes it definite ...

Comment: @DieterLücking I am fairly new to c++, what do you mean?

Comment: @Predator44 After changing the question again: `(*p++); ` is undefined behaviour (see operator precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is undefined behavour. You leave the range of the `int` you are allowed to point to by incrementing the pointer. The compiler is allowed to do everything it wants to do with your code.

Answer (score -4):

This happened to me once when I was writing an operating system.

The bug took forever to find.

The heap was corrupted because one of my string functions wrote into adjacent memory.